# Optimize Group by & Order by query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

This is structure of product table.
Currently have more 1 million records.
I have performance issue when I use query group by & order by.
[image]

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT product_name FROM vs_product GROUP BY store_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

How to improve this query to perform faster? I indexed the store_id, ID is primary key.

Comment: What indexes are on the table?

Comment: id - PRIMARY (index name), store_id - store_id (index name)

Comment: Can you explain what this query is trying to do?  "Selecting two arbitrary product names from stores in reverse order of id" does not seem particularly useful.

Comment: ok. i want to retrieve product by latest listed date and only 1 record from each store (store_id)

Answer (score 0):

You want a query like this:

```
select p.*
from product p join
      (select store_id, max(id) as maxid
       from product p
       group by store_id
      ) psum
      on psum.store_id = p.store_id and p.id = maxid
```

You don't have date in any of the tables, so I'm assuming the largest id is the most recent.

Comment: you don't need to output `store_id` in the subquery, and you should join on your `maxid`.

Comment: @newtover . . . Thank you for catching the problem on the join.  This query is based on the comment.  The original query doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
   FROM my_table x
  JOIN (SELECT store_id, MAX(id) max_id FROM my_table GROUP BY store_id) y
    ON y.store_id = x.store_id
   AND y.max_id = x.id
 ORDER 
    BY store_id DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: joining on `max_id` is enough, since `id` is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky (but fast) solution:

```
SELECT product_name
FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM vs_product
  GROUP BY store_id DESC
  LIMIT 2) as ids
JOIN vs_product USING (id);
```

**How it works**:

Your index on store_id stores (store_id, id) pairs in ascending order. `GROUP BY DESC` will make MySQL read the index in reverse order, that is the subquery will fetch the maximum ids for each store_id. Then you just join them back to the whole table to fetch product names.

Take notice, that the query will fetch two product names for the store ids with the maximum values.